# Can you use Multilevel Modeling (aka Hierarchical Linear Modeling) with Sequential Linear Modeling?

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, multilevel-analysis, stepwise-regression, sequential-analysis

I have a question regarding the use of Multilevel Modeling (aka Hierarchical Linear Modeling) with Sequential Linear Modeling.

I am trying to perform Sequential Linear Modeling (with a binary outcome) but I also want to take into account two levels of the data. Specifically, I have data taken from multiple schools and I want to have a second level for school - which would require me to use Multilevel Modeling.

My question is, is there a way to perform both analyses at the same time?

The alternative I have thought of is to perform Sequential Linear Modeling and separately perform Multilevel Modeling and report there was (not) nesting effects of school.

Comment: What do you mean with *Sequential Linear Modeling*?

Comment: By Sequential Linear Modeling, I mean the predictors are entered sequentially or in steps/blocks to determine the information gained by adding another predictor or sets of predictors.

Comment: So that is stepwise methods? Then maybe add the tag [tag:stepwise-regression]

Comment: Yes, and thank you I will add that now.

Answer (score 0):

Stepwise modelling is a fairly simple approach, so I don't see why it couldn't be done.  Simply select your criterion for calling a model "better", and implement the stepwise procedure using a hierarchical model.

The question shouldn't be "can it be done" but rather "should it be done" and the evidence would suggest the answer would be: **NO**.  You're free to search this site for threads on stepwise selection to see why this is so problematic.